# CodeIgniter: Session values lost on redirect

Tags: codeigniter

I set session in a controller method like & redirect to some other controller.

```
$search = array(
    'search_count' => count($data['result']),
    'projectInfo' => $data['result']
    );

$this->session->set_userdata($search);
redirect('projects');
```

but if I try to access this variable in other controller it shows nothing:

```
print_r($this->session->userdata('projectInfo'));
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414178/saving-array-to-session-in-codeigniter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431250/size-of-session-in-codeigniter http://stackoverflow.com/a/4431300/1273830 I am sure you will find the answer in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved I used [PHP Native Session class](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session)

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! but it does seems to be working now and do you mean don't use codeigniter sessions if they are giving error

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
redirect('projects', 'refresh');
```

instead. Setting cookies with HTTP redirect doesn't work on all browsers.

Comment: There r some limits for CI session & CI session does not acts like PHP $_SESSION. I also faced this problem & what I did I just set reference id in my case db row ids & then acess them but it is not what i exactly want but to move forward I used this approach :(