# codeigniter set multidimensional array in session

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am facing an issue to add multidimensional array to codeigniter session.

i want to store a multidimensional array result to session or any other that variable i used after my adding process i want use that variable.

also tried to store simple array to store in session and they works but in my array this is notworking so please help friends

Please check below for my array structure,

Thanks in advance!

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
   (
       [user_id] => 11
       [fb_id] => 0
       [am_id] => 0
       [cm_id] => 
   )
)
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: use jsonencode to convert this array to json string and save it to session.
And use json decode to convert the string back to array.
I guess session do not store datastructues, it stores string values

Comment: can you please a give a example..thanks

Comment: Thanks brother...it's working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `serialize` method before storing multidimensional array to session. It is the better idea for storing multi dimensional array to session as a string and you can access this whenever needed by `unserialize` method.

Comment: you call like this $this->session->set_userdata('findcaddie',serialize($array_mail));

Comment: yes array stored in session but i can't access to this to other page

Comment: $user_data = unserialize($this->session->userdata('findcaddie'));
echo $user_data['user_id']; like this. not tested this

Comment: i have an issue with my data is not stored in session

Comment: $user_data = unserialize($this->session->userdata('findcaddie')); not working

Comment: how you are saving your array to session?

Comment: What is the size of your session array? If its too big, CI have limitation to save in session.

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431250/size-of-session-in-codeigniter

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 11
            [fb_id] => 0
            [am_id] => 0
            [cm_id] => 
            ..
            ..
            ..
            
        )

)

Comment: Thanks brother yo to for give a greate response